# track multiple identical entries

Tags: mysql

I got a table that I am allowing identical entries (duplicates, triplecates etc.) but I also got a column that I want everytime that an entry is being made to be updated with the how many times that entry exists.

So I thought to write a trigger, I can already find the duplicate entries by doing

```
select count(pid) from items group by pid having count(*);
```

but the thing is that this query returns less columns that the orinal table (cause there are many duplicates)

so there is no 1 to 1 relation between the query and the table so I can use update. How could I modify this to get the desired result

thank you in advanced.

Comment: why do you need the extra column? Can you simply not run a count by pid when you need that bit of information?

Comment: cause there are thousands of entries and more and more are added continiously and when someone views some entries its usually a hundend or so...so i cant run the same query a hundrends times. its not practical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem that you'll face here is that MySQL will not allow you to modify the `items` table using an `AFTER INSERT ...` trigger following a modification to the `items` table itself (think of how this could lead to a circular reference).

One solution is to store the counts in a separate table altogether (say `items_pid_info`). The primary key of this table would be `pid` and it is this table that would be updated by the triggers on the main items table. When you need to access the `pidCount` for a given `pid` simply join onto this table and you will have up-to-date pid counts for your given pid. Hence:

```
create table items_pid_info    
(pid int unsigned not null primary key,
pidCount int unsigned not null);
```

Now create `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers on your `items` table to update the `items_pid_info` table:

```
DELIMITER &&

CREATE TRIGGER items_pid_count_ins_trg
AFTER INSERT ON items

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE c int;

set c := (select count(*) from items im where im.pid = NEW.pid);

insert into items_pid_info values (NEW.pid,c) on duplicate key update pidCount = c;

END&&


CREATE TRIGGER items_pid_count_upd_trg
AFTER UPDATE ON items
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE c int;

set c := (select count(*) from items im where im.pid = NEW.pid);

insert into items_pid_info values (NEW.pid,c) on duplicate key update pidCount = c;
END&&


CREATE TRIGGER items_pid_count_del_trg
AFTER DELETE ON items
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE c int;

set c := (select count(*) from items im where im.pid = OLD.pid);

insert into items_pid_info values (OLD.pid,c) on duplicate key update pidCount = c;
END&&

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it helped a lot, iam quite new to mysql and when I was using oracle I could easily do that on the same table (to do an autonumbering for example) thank you